# How do I mitigate memory leaks when recursively calling a function inside a Future[T]?

Tags: scala, recursion, concurrency, playframework, tail-recursion

This question is inspired by some comments in an earlier Stackoverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973838/how-do-i-make-this-tail-recursive) on the same topic and also motivated by some code I'm writing as well. Given the example contained therein, I'm somewhat convinced that this pattern is tail recursive. If this is the case, how do I mitigate the memory leak posed by accumulating futures whose underlying threads never join the ForkJoinPool from which they were spawned?

```
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution.Implicits.defaultExecutionContext
import play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient
import scala.util.{Success,Failure}

object Client {
 val client = new NingWSClient(new Builder().build())
 def print = Iteratee.foreach { chunk: Array[Byte] => println(new String(chunk)) }

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
   connect()
   def connect(): Unit = {
     val consumer = client.url("http://streaming.resource.com")
     consumer.get(_ => print).onComplete {
       case Success(s) => println("Success")
       case Failure(f) => println("Recursive retry"); connect()
     }
   }
 }
}
```

In the example I've shared, the `get[A](...)` method returns a `Future[Iteratee[Array[Byte],A]]`. The author of the above article I've included remarks that "scala.concurrent Futures don't get merged" once they return but that Twitter's futures some how manage this. I'm using the PlayFramework implementation, however, which uses futures provided by the standard Scala 2.1X library.

Do any of you have evidence that support or dismiss these claims? Does my code pose a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you linked (was in a comment, not the question or answer) refers to a memory leak that occurred with `flatMap`. Your code doesn't use `flatMap`, so I don't think you wouldn't run into any problems, as you're just conditionally executing another `Future` via a callback, and not caring at all about the previous.

Either way, it's kind of irrelevant because this issue was fixed in 2.10.3. See issue [SI-7336](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7336) and the [pull request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2674) that fixes it for more info.

Answer (score 1):

While your call does not suffer from the stack overflow dangers of regular recursive calls, it is not tail recursive either. The exit statement of `connect()` is `onComplete` which simply lets `connect()` exit and release its stack. The "recursive" call to `connect()` actually happens as a continuation when the future completes and therefore is not an actual recursion.

*Caveat*: if `get` actually always returned a `Future.successful` (as it might in a unit test), chances are that `get` could suffer from a stack overflow, since the `Success` case would like trigger immediately and before `onComplete` exited. I haven't tested this and it might be something that may or may not happen depending on the `ExecutionContext`'s properties.