# How make tail recursion in scala from Future.foreach call back?

Tags: scala, recursion, callback, future

Consider a scala code:

```
def myRecursiveFunction(id:string):Unit= {
    myAsyncDao.search(id).foreach {response=>
        myRecursiveFunction(response.id)
    }
}
//myAsyncDao.search returns a Future
//response have id field for further computations
```

If I put `@tailrec` on top op function, compile complains `Recusive call not in tail position`.

Can it be optimizated as tail recursion?

Comment: As you can read [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16986416/2522681) your solution does not require tail recursion because the stack does not grow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
def myRecursiveFunction(id:string):Future[Unit]= {
    myAsyncDao.search(id) flatMap {response=>
        myRecursiveFunction(response.id)
    }
}
```

Update:

```
def search(id: Future[Int]) = Future { 5 }

@tailrec
def myRecursiveFunction(id: Future[Int]):Future[Unit]= {
    val response = search(id)
    myRecursiveFunction(response)    
}
```

Comment: Did you even try it before posting ? It does not work still the same error.

Comment: With the exception that the OP's `search` function does not take a `Future[Int]` but instead a `String` which makes the situation more complex, unfortunately.