# Tail-recursive, functional polling in Scala

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have a function that looks for an `Elephant` over a network, returning a `Future[Option[Elephant]]`. The return value is a `Future` so that the function can return immediately while the network call happens asynchronously. It contains an `Option` for which `None` means not yet available, while `Some` means the elephant has been found:

```
def checkForElephant : Future[Option[Elephant]] = ???
```

What I'd like to do is write a function called `pollForElephant`.

```
def pollForElephant : Future[Elephant] = ???
```

This function should return a `Future` over a process that will call `checkForElephant` and succeed quickly if an element is found on the first check, but thereafter to check again every 10 seconds until an `Elephant` is found, even if there are no elephants and it has to try forever.

The easy way to do this is just to force the check to be synchronous, write a recursive function outside of the `Future` domain to poll, and then create a `Future` over the whole affair:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.{Await,Future,blocking}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Elephant;

def checkForElephant : Future[Option[Elephant]] = ???

def synchronousCheckForElephant : Option[Elephant] = blocking {
  Await.result( checkForElephant, Duration.Inf )
}

@tailrec
def poll( last : Option[Elephant] ) : Elephant = {
  last match {
    case Some( elephant ) => elephant
    case None => {
      blocking {
        Thread.sleep( 10.seconds.toMillis )
      }
      poll( synchronousCheckForElephant )
    }
  }
}

def pollForElephant : Future[Elephant] = Future {
   poll( synchronousCheckForElephant )
}
```

This seems terribly inelegant, to start from the `Future` domain, force into synchrony, and then go back. I thought I should be able to do everything from the `Future`. So, I tried this:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.{Await,Future,blocking}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Elephant;

def checkForElephant : Future[Option[Elephant]] = ???

// oops! this is not @tailrec
def poll( last : Future[Option[Elephant]] ) : Future[Elephant] = {
  last.flatMap { mbElephant =>
    mbElephant match {
      case Some( elephant ) => Future.successful( elephant )
      case None => {
        blocking {
          Thread.sleep( 10.seconds.toMillis )
        }
        poll( checkForElephant )
      }
    }
  }
}

def pollForElephant : Future[Elephant] = poll( checkForElephant )
```

Unfortunately, as the comment above says, the `poll(...)` function is not tail recursive. Elephants might take a long time to arrive, and I'm supposed to wait indefinitely, but the stack might blow.

And the whole thing feels a little weird. Should I just revert to the easier-to-reason-about synchronous approach? Is there a safe way to do what I mean to while staying in the `Future`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973838/how-do-i-make-a-function-involving-futures-tail-recursive

Comment: @PH88 thanks. that's helpful and interesting. i have to think about it for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @PH88 comment: you don't need call to be tail recursive since in `checkForElephant` inside your `flatMap` you create a new `Future` and thus new stack. Here is a simple code I tried to mock your `checkForElephant`:

```
type Elephant = String
val rnd = new Random()

def checkForElephant: Future[Option[Elephant]] = Future({
  val success = rnd.nextDouble() < 0.2
  println(s"Call to checkForElephant => $success")
  if (success) Some(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().mkString("\n")) else None
})

def poll(last: Future[Option[Elephant]]): Future[Elephant] = {
  last flatMap {
      case Some(elephant) => Future.successful(elephant)
      case None => {
        blocking {
          println("Sleeping")
          Thread.sleep(100.millisecond.toMillis)
        }
        poll(checkForElephant)
      }
    }
 }

def pollForElephant: Future[Elephant] = poll(checkForElephant)

val result = Await.result(pollForElephant, Duration.Inf)
println(result)
```

And here is output from one of runs:

> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => false
>   
> Sleeping
>   
> Call to checkForElephant => true
>   
> java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1556)
>   
> so.TestApp$$anonfun$so$TestApp$$checkForElephant$1$1.apply(TestApp.scala:97)
>   
> so.TestApp$$anonfun$so$TestApp$$checkForElephant$1$1.apply(TestApp.scala:94)
>   
> scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>   
> scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>   scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
>   
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
>   
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
>   
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   
> scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

You may see that despite the fact that `checkForElephant` returned `None` first 7 times, stack trace is shallow.

**Sidenote**

What I don't like about your approach is the fact that you just block some thread when you do sleep for 10 seconds. This seems rather inefficient to me. If you want to have many such calls, you might consider using something smarter such as Java [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) or Akka Actors.

**Update**

> But would it leak memory, the logical equivalent of stack frames, maintained as objects on the heap?

No, it should not unless you have something very strange in your `checkForElephant`. To have a memory leak some memory should be retained by some "root". Possible roots are: static variables, thread local variables and stack. As we know stack doesn't grow so it can't be a source of the leak. If you don't mess up with something static and/or thread local, you should be safe.

As to ***threads consumption***, if you really have just one "elephant" in the system, I don't think there is anything significantly better. However if your `checkForElephant` is actually `checkForElephant(id)`, then you might consume a lot of threads for no good reason. First step to improve this might be using `Promise` and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (I'm not aware of Scala equivalent for it) and sacrifice some functional style for better thread usage such as:

```
// Just 1 thread should be enough assuming checkForElephant schedules 
// it's Future on some executor rather than current thread
val scheduledExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)

def pollForElephant: Future[Elephant] = {
  def scheduleDelayedPoll(p: Promise[Elephant]) = {
    scheduledExecutor.schedule(new Runnable {
      override def run() = poll(p)
    },
      10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }

  def poll(p: Promise[Elephant]): Unit = {
    checkForElephant.onComplete {
      case s: Success[Option[Elephant]] => if (s.value.isDefined) p.success(s.value.get) else scheduleDelayedPoll(p)
      case f: Failure[_] => scheduleDelayedPoll(p)
    }
  }

  val p = Promise[Elephant]()
  poll(p)
  p.future
}
```

If you have more load, next step would be using some non-blocking I/O for your `checkForElephant` to not block threads for requests over network. If you actually use a Web-service, take a look at [Play WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS) which is a Scala-wrapper around [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) which is in turn based on [Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty)

Comment: I agree that this is an awkward way to poll. Part of the motivation for the question is whether there is a less awkward way within the straightforward tooling of `Future`,  since the `checkForElephant(...)` method puts me there anyway. Maybe down the line I'll look for a better solution and bridge it into the `Future` API with a `Promise`.

Comment: You and @PH88 are right (thanks for the experimental confirmation!) that stack is not what this code leaks. But would it leak memory, the logical equivalent of stack frames, maintained as objects on the heap? Empirically, it seems not to leak Threads, which I thought it might. Just one Thread of a fork/join pool seems to be consumed at any time, sleeping peacefully. This might not be so bad.

Comment: @SteveWaldman, if you get back to this question, please take a look at my update where I tried to address some of your comments.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I've implemented the basic approach you suggest here https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mchange/sc/v2/concurrent/Poller.scala