# While Loop with Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have two methods:

`def getNextJob: Future[Option[Job]]`

`def process(job: Job): Future[Unit]`

I would like to process all Jobs until there are no jobs remaining.

I can do this with `Await` e.g.

```
private def process()(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = {
    var job: Option[Job] = Await.result(service.getNextJob, FiniteDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    while(job.isDefined) {
      Await.result(process(job.get), FiniteDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      job = Await.result(service.getNextJob, FiniteDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    }
    Future.successful()
  }
```

But this is ugly and doesn't use Futures properly. Is there a way I could chain the futures somehow to replace this?

Comment: Do you want to `process` jobs in strict order as in your example code, or can they be executed in any order?

Comment: @Tim Any order is fine, I just need to ensure 1 runs at once

Comment: I guess I am confused about why `process` returns a `Future` if you always wait for it to complete before moving on to the next job. If you don't wait for it to complete then multiple jobs could be processed at the same time.

Comment: @Tim I wasn't going to go into the implementation but `getNextJob` just pulls one job that has status `unprocessed` from the database. `process` processes it and updates the status to `done`. If I processed multiple in parallel there is no guarantee (with my current implementation) that the job would only ever run once as two calls to `getNextJob` could potentially return the same job twice`

Comment: In that case you should probably avoid returning `Future` from `process` and just make it do the processing and then return `Unit`. This is already running in the `Future` from `getNextJob` so there is no need to have another `Future` nested inside the first `Future`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def go()(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
  getNextJob.flatMap { maybeJob ⇒
    if(maybeJob.isDefined) process(maybeJob.get).flatMap(_ ⇒ go())
    else Future.unit
  }
```

**Note:** It is not tail recursive.

Comment: It is actually not recursive at all :) Note, that `Option.get` is "code smell", and should be avoided. You should use something like `case Some(job) => process(job).flatMap(_ => go()) ; case None => Future.unit` instead

Comment: I went with the suggestions from @Dima for this answer, many thanks!

Comment: Note that since it's a future, the function not being tail recursive shouldn't be a problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986416/1507124

Answer (score 3):

```
def processAll()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
  getNextJob.flatMap {
    case Some(job) => process(job).flatMap(_ => processAll())
    case None => Future.unit
  }
```

To process them all possibly concurrently:

```
def processAll()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] =
  getNextJob.flatMap {
    case Some(job) => process(job).zipWith(processAll())((_,_) => ())
    case None => Future.unit
  }
```

Comment: this will process the jobs one at a time, correct? If so, how to modify it to process the jobs concurrently?

Comment: @CervEd Added that. Warning though, I wrote it from memory so it might not compile

Comment: Thank you! I used something like `Future.sequence { (1 to X).map(processAll(...)) }`, where X is how many requests I wanted processed at a time, but it felt incorrect